# Amazon EC2 Linux 2 PHP GMP install/enable

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gmp

I have a new instance of EC2 running Amazon Linux2 with PHP. I am unable to enable PHP GMP for CLI. I am able to install GMP using:

```
`yum install gmp-devel`
```

I have also tried modifying my php.ini by adding:

```
`extension=gmp.so`
```

and restarting the web server. I cannot find any documentation on GMP other than Amazon stating that the GMP extension is part of the core. (https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/) I am verifying the extension using PHP as follows:

```
`if (!extension_loaded("gmp")) die("NO GMP");`
```

Soooo aggravating! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.
you can restart app server from elastic beanstalk for fixed this issue
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spoxD.png)